# How do I express three desired basis vectors as a quaternion?

Tags: vector-spaces, control-theory, quaternions

I am creating a simulation that relies on the controller developed in the paper "Automatic Re-Initialization and Failure Recovery for Aggressive Flight with a Monocular Vision-Based Quadrotor" which can be found here: http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/ICRA15_Faessler.pdf

On page 5 of the paper it states "Now, the full desired attitude $\boldsymbol{q}_{des}$ can be built from the three desired body axes $\boldsymbol{e}_{x,des}^{B}$, $\boldsymbol{e}_{y,des}^{B}$, $\boldsymbol{e}_{z,des}^{B}$."

How do I build a quaternion from the three basis vectors?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [Wahba's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem), which is stated for rotation matrices as

$$
\min_{R\in SO(3)} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \left\|w_k - R\,v_k\right\|^2, \tag{1}
$$

where $v_k$ and $w_k$ are vectors in reference frame $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ respectively and the minimizing $R$ should be the best approximation of the rotation from frame $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. When reconstructing the attitude of something the vectors $v_k$ and $w_k$ can both either be measured or known directions. For example the directions of gravity would be known in the world frame and could be measured in the body frame of a drone. It can be noted that $(1)$ does not have a unique solution when the rank of $\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_N\end{bmatrix}$ and the rank of $\begin{bmatrix}w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_N\end{bmatrix}$ are both less than two.

A similar optimization problem could also be formulated for quaternions by replacing $R\,v_k$ in $(1)$ with the vector $v_k$ rotated by a unit quaternion. There are also multiple algorithms known which can solve Wahba's problem for quaternions, such as [QUEST](https://doi.org/10.2514/3.19717), [ESOQ](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/D_Mortari/publication/254199735_ESOQ_A_closed-form_solution_to_the_Wahba_problem/links/56573d2308ae4988a7b533e2.pdf) and [FOMA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930015542.pdf).

Comment: I have three basis vectors forming the coordinate system, as far as I can tell this approach only uses two vectors. Additionally, I don't think I need to describe the rotation from one coordinate system to another, I just need some way to capture the coordinate system information using a quaternion.

Comment: @varlotbarnacle the paper from your question states: "$q$ is the orientation of the quadrotor’s body coordinates with respect to the world coordinates", so the unit quaternion translates between two coordinate frames. Namely that paper says that one can construct a desired attitude from three desired vectors in the body frame ($N=3$ though the 3rd vector is constructed using the crossproduct between the first two, but $N=2$ would be enough and the 3rd could be omitted). Here it is implied that the corresponding vectors in the world frame are known (probably the columns of an identity matrix).